# How to add images for backgrounds in each section of a one-page scrollable webpage?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web

I'm doing the FreeCodeCamp web dev course, and I'm stuck on making my profile page. The website needs to have more than 3 sections and should have only one page. What I wanted is a different image as a background for each. So far, I have only been able to add the first image and text, and have smooth scrolling. I have been trying to add the other images since weeks now, but it just doesn't work.

Also, I want the text to stay at the same place, but the images to scroll, which again isn't happening.

I'm using codepen.io and Bootstrap. I will add a link of my pen so that you guys can see the code.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to ask the question, but I have added all the information I can provide. Thanks in advance!

Link to me pen: http://codepen.io/AnInternetUser/pen/LNKGMY

Code:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('.nav li a').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if ($target.length) {
            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop : targetOffset
            }, 750);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.hello {
  padding-top: 70px;
  background-image: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/aninternetuser/image/upload/v1463638974/hd-wallpaper-40_cdz9co.jpg');
  repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hello h1 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 125px;
}

.hello h3 {
 font-family: Oswald;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: grey;
}

.experience {
  background-image: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/aninternetuser/image/upload/v1463648167/desktop-desktops-highway-night-photo-hdwallpapers2016com_hcpltl.jpg');
  repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
 <html>
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Krunal Rindani</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="hello" id="home" style="min-height:1000px;min-width:1000px;">
        <h1></h1>
        <h1></h1>
        <h1>Hello.</h1>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h3>This is my portfolio website. You can find my contact details and past work here. You can also learn more about me here!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="projects" class="experience" sytle="min-height:1000px;min-width:1000px;">
        <h2>This area will be updated with all the web projects done by me. Stay tuned!</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="about" style="min-height:1000px;">

    </div>

    <div id="contact" style="min-height:1000px;">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the codepen link?

Comment: Please, to make things easier for us, provide a snippet inside your question instead of an external codepen link. That way, in a year from now, people reading your question won't run into a dead codepen link.

Comment: @randy I did that. Sorry I didn't do it earlier.

Comment: You were fast :P Good job!

Comment: @user2517200 Added the link and the snippet

Comment: @randy Haha! I had forgotten to add the codepen link when I stumbled upon the snippet option.

Comment: @KrunalRindani maybe this will help? http://codepen.io/ojbravo/pen/BszEq

Comment: @user2517200 that is exactly what I'm looking for, except I want images instead of the plain backgrounds.

Comment: @KrunalRindani so here you go, replace them

Comment: @user2517200 The design is vastly different. When I said that's exactly what I wanted, I meant the overall feel and not the design elements like the navbar etc.